# RAML 1.0 representation of Java Map

Tags: java, raml, raml-java-parser, raml-1.0

I have RAML schema which contains       `"javaType": "java.util.Map<String, java.util.List<Employee>>"`

I have separate schema (employee.schema) available which represent class Employee.

But as I have not used employee.schema in RAML so it is not generating class Employee and throws an Error while converting RAML to Java.

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "description": "Desc",
  "properties": {
    "employeeGroups": {
      "type": "object",
      "javaType": "java.util.Map<String, java.util.List<Employee>>"
    }
  },
  "additionalProperties": false
}
```

Can anybody share comments how to represent `"javaType": "java.util.Map<String, java.util.List<Employee>>"` in RAML ?

```
RAML Version: 1.0
```

Comment: you could use a jsonschema definition of a map, but no sure raml-java-parser will handle it, maybe try first with a simpler map to see if it works, like: "mapInt": {
      "type": "object",
      "additionalProperties": {"type": "integer"}
    }

Comment: You said: "But as I have not used employee.schema in RAML so it is not generating class Employee...". Why would you _expect_ it to work when you are not including one of the dependencies in your RAML? Have you tried adding an include statement to the RAML before generating the Java?

Comment: Have you tried creating a Wrapper class and reference it in the RAML instead the Map one?

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 options here.

The **first one** is to just include the external file with the schema in the `types` definition of your `raml` file.

For instance, assuming that:

- The object represented in your example is called `EmployeeGroupsContainer`,
- And the file with the `Employee` schema is called `employee.schema` and is in the same directory as the `raml`file.

The `types` section would look like this:

```yaml
types:
    EmployeeGroupsContainer:
        schema: |
                  {
                    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/schema#",
                    "type": "object",
                    "description": "Desc",
                    "properties": {
                      "employeeGroups": {
                        "type": "object",
                        "javaType": "java.util.Map<String, java.util.List<Employee>>"
                      }
                    },
                    "additionalProperties": false
                  }
    Employee:
        schema:
            !include employee.schema
```

This would be the recomended approach and the one I would use.

A **second option** would be to previously generate the `Employee` object, and once you have it you can generate the rest because the `Employee` class would now be in your classpath. The best way to do this is by two separate executions of the tool you use to generate the code (the first one with `employee.schema` to generate the `Employee` class, and the second one with the rest).

May be you are tempted to generate `Employee` once and move it to `src/main/java`, but I would recommend against this, as keeping generated code versioned (in git or any other VCS) is always a bad practice. Code generation should always be a part of the overall build process (tipically with a maven plugin, if you use maven).

The only scenario I can think of to choose the second approach instead of the first one is that you don't have access to the main `raml` file. But if you do have it, I would definitely go for the first approach.